# Testing cached function only called once

Tags: python, caching, python-decorators

```
@cached(cache=TTLCache(maxsize=1024, ttl=600))
def get_data(self, key) :
    result = self.get_result(key)
    return result

def test_get_data(self):
    my_class = MyClass()
    my_class.get_data.return_value = 'text'
    my_class.get_data('id')
    my_class.get_data('id')
    my_class.get_result.assert_called_once()
```

> E           AssertionError: Expected 'get_result' to have been called
> once. Called 2 times.

How do I test the inner method is called once?

Comment: Why do you call `get_result()` twice, but expect it to be called once?

Comment: I fixed. I call get_data twice expecting once call to get_result. How can i do that?

Comment: Please update your question with the details of how you have used mocking. We need to be able to reproduce your actual result.

Comment: I call get_data twice but it gives that error.

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial, I wanted to say that you haven't posted enough relevant code.

But it turns out the problem is so obvious I don't know why you missed it. It is in your function definition of `test_get_data`.

You called `my_class.get_result('id')` twice, of course it is called twice. It is literally what you wrote. The computer only does exactly what you told it.

If you want to use cache, and call `get_result` only once, based on what you wrote, you need to call `get_data` instead of `get_result`.

```
def test_get_data(self):
    my_class = MyClass()
    my_class.get_data('id')
    my_class.get_data('id')
    my_class.get_result.assert_called_once()
```

But then you are initializing an unnecessary instance when you have an already instantiated object. Just use `self`:

```
def test_get_data(self):
    self.get_data('id')
    self.get_data('id')
    self.get_result.assert_called_once()
```

It should be working now.

Also, another issue, don't assign named variables to values that are immediately returned. Inline them and return directly.

```
@cached(cache=TTLCache(maxsize=1024, ttl=600))
def get_data(self, key) :
    return self.get_result(key)
```

Comment: I have miss written. I called get_data twice but it gives that error. And the test class and the and other one are in different files.